# Setting UILabel Text Multiple Times Within A Loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm fooling around in XCode, trying to learn a little about the iOS SDK and Objective-C.

I have this for loop below, and it should print out several values to the screen (depending on the amount of months chosen), but instead, it's only printing out the final value.

Can anybody point out why?

Thanks a bunch, in advance!

```
for (int i = 1; i <= myMonthsDouble; i++)
{
    myPaymentAmount = (myBalanceDouble/10) + myInterestDouble;
    myBalanceDouble -= myPaymentAmount;
    //convert myPaymentAmount double into string named myPaymentAmountString
    NSString *myPaymentAmountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myPaymentAmount];
    NSString *paymentInformation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ months, %@ per month.", monthsString, myPaymentAmountString];
    myInterestDouble = (myBalanceDouble * (myInterestDouble/100))/12;
    self.label.text = paymentInformation;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any statements that would cause print outs at all (except for the commented out C++ code). Did you post the right snippet?

Comment: If you mean "printing" via self.label.text, the loop runs far to quickly to see the intermediate results.

Comment: @Perception - Yeah, to practice, I was converting a C++ program into Objective C, that comment just stayed in.

Comment: @Sebastian and bchurchill, yeah, I mean how can I print out all of the values from the loop into the label text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only printing the last value to the screen because you only have one label. Each time you get to the end of the loop, you are setting that label's text which is overriding the last value. If you want to print all of them to the screen, you will need to have either multiple labels or you will have to append the strings together and put them in either a label or a `UITextView` that is formatted so that they can all be seen (most likely a text view but it can be done with a label.)

One example of doing this would be:

```
label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:newString];
numLines++; //this starts at 0;
```

and then at the end:

```
label.numberOfLines = numLines;
```

Comment: Note: You will also have to edit the label's frame such that everything is visible.

Comment: Would you believe, I couldn't get this to work for about half an hour. It kept breaking off...so I closed XCODE. I came back two hours later and just pushed "run" and it worked.